# Use of Undeclared Type 'AVCamViewController'

Tags: iphone, swift, ios7, objectcontext

I'm new to the coding industry and am seriously struggling with Swift. I have a situation where I want to go from one page to another, but I keep getting an error of "use of undeclared type `AVCamViewController`. This is my code:

```
@IBAction func goToApp(sender : AnyObject) {
        let AVCam = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AVCam") as? AVCamViewController.h
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(AVCam, animated: true)
    }
```

And if I try to import the AVCamViewController or `AVCamViewController.h` or `AVCamViewController.m`, I get an error of 'no such module'.

I have have all the files of the AVCam application in my app so I am not sure what to do. Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove .h from line when you instantiate vc:

```
let AVCam = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AVCam") as? AVCamViewController
```

AVCamViewController.h is file name but you need class name which is AVCamViewController

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a bridging header set up? If `AVCamViewController` is a system class, you have to `@import` the right framework, i.e. `@import AVFoundation`. Otherwise, you have to create a header specifically for use as a bridge from Objective C to Swift. In said header, you include your own headers that you want Swift to see. You will have to set the build settings to point to the new header. If you added a new Swift class/file, Xcode should have asked if it could create one automatically. If you do have one, you can put your header imports/includes into that file.